# How to get SQLCode even when no exception is thrown from DB2 database using OleDbConnection class in C#.NET

Tags: c#, db2, oledbconnection

1. How to get sqlcode even when no exception is thrown from DB2 database using OleDbConnection class in C#.NET?

For example:

When there are no rows returned for update & delete query the sqlcode is 100 but how will I get it in OledbConnection?

2. As well when using the select query when no rows are returned, I need to get the SQLCode `? SQLCode = 0 Successfull` , `SQLCode = <0 Exceptions`, `SQLCode  > 0 Warnings ( 100 - no rows returned )`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the IBM Data Server provider for .Net instead of the generic OLEDB provider; the IBM provider has the [DB2Error class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ErrorClass.html), which has the information you want to retrieve.

Comment: I am working on migration project and there are some limitations changing the way it actually working .Oledb is used in current project and we are trying to use new helper file and the current one(dll) is not much flexible.

Comment: So If we are using IBM Data Server provider do we get SQLCode even when there is no exception ...
We use inline query and NOT Stored Procedure from C# to DB2 ... 

I need SQLCode = 100 which happens in the case if no rows are returned for where condition while updating and delete . Or a select query ......
Even if we get in which object can we find the sqlcode ( when there is no execption ) ....... Please help .......